# Show my location using google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to do this.When a user comes to sites,i need to show him on google map and also will pass some latitude and longitude.Now my map has to show the path of user and the lat and long which i pass.

Using my below code,i pass my lat and long.Now,i need to show the user position.

How to show both this?

```
       function initialize() {

   var myOptions = {
   zoom: 17,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.333,34.534),
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                              myOptions);

  var image = 'image.png';
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.333,34.534);
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: image
   });
   } 

[This is how i tried]:http://dpaste.com/695949/ 
  it did not work.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display directions on google map you need to have source and destination latlong. in your above code you have destination latlong but user latlong are missing. you need to first get user latlong then you have to use google direction renderer. for more reference read http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/directions.html

user(source) latlong can be found in many ways -

1. using `geocoder` gem based on `ip, address`, etc.
2. using `html5 geolocation` read http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/html5-geolocation/

Comment: :How do i make changes in this http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel.html source code.How to pass my lat and lang

Comment: just declared sourceaddr & destaddr as js variable and use them wherever required

Comment: :check this dpaste.com/695949

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use HTML5 geo location then in your initialize function after you add the beachMarker put:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(e.coords.latitude, e.coords.longitude);
    });
  }, function() {
    // Handle error here
  });
}
```